# Layout with DIV element

Tags: html, css

I have trouble to generate the following layout using DIV element, fighting with alignement and box style

[Desire layout is here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9ECBD63702497F70!12562&authkey=!ALDJM0RIMwhPo54&v=3&ithint=photo%2CPNG)

Any help would be helpfull

regards

Comment: css: `display: table` etc. would be easiest. Naturally allows the vertical and horizontal alignment. (Using table elements for non-tabular data is poor, but div's styled like a table isn't breaking the semantic implications.)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/399/)**

```css
.element {
  margin: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.remaining, .sold {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.remaining {
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
}

.remaining:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FF7F7E;
  content: "SHOES - STOCK";
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top, .center, .bottom {
  display: table-row;
}

.top .inner {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.center span {
  display: block;
}

.bottom .inner {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.inner-content {
  display: table;
}

.top .inner span,
.bottom .inner span{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}


.top .inner span:last-child,
.bottom .inner span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
}

.center span:first-child {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
}

span u {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  .remaining, .sold {
    display: table;
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .remaining, .sold {
    display: table;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }

  .remaining {
    border-right: 1px solid #999999;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="remaining">

    <div class="top">
      <div class="inner">
          <div class="inner-content">
              <span>TOTAL</span>
              <span>250 <u>pcs</u></span> 
          </div>      
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
       <span>200</span>
       <span>REMAINING</span>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="inner-content">
          <span>USED</span>
          <span>50 <u>pcs</u></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="sold">
    <div class="center">
      <span>50</span>
      <span>SOLD</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```